# In kotlin, when @Column(nullable = false) is marked, the queried entity must always be written "!!"

Tags: kotlin, jpa, intellij-idea

In kotlin,
When writing entity classes, the default values of attributes are null,
The annotation of the attribute is `@Column(nullable = false)`, which indicates that it cannot be empty.
For example, the following `username`:

```
@Entity
class Users {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var username: String? = null
}
```

When querying, `findById` returns the following result:
`val user = Users(username:"MyName")`

When calling `user. username!!` I have to bring `!!`,
because the annotation is `@Column(nullable = false)`.

This creates a problem:
When I get the `username`, I always have to check whether the `@Column` annotation of `username` is marked as empty or not, and then I can judge whether I should write `!!` or not.
This is very troublesome, and I always write what should not be written on `!!` carelessly.

What can I do to prevent the IDEA compiler from reporting errors when I mark `@Column(nullable = false)` and do not write `!!`?

If it is written like this (give the attribute a default value):

```
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var username: String = "default"
```

When using `findById` to query, I must bring `withIgnorePaths`, which is more troublesome:

```
val matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("username", ...))
Example.of(Users(username:""),matcher)
```

Comment: I hardly know Kotlin, but has this really anything todo with the `@Column` annotation? Isn't that just normal Kotlins null type safety? You are assigning a nullable type to a non nullable, therefore you need the proper operator.

Answer (score 1):

Approaches to avoid `!!` in your case.

1. The easiest one, make `username` not null, so each time you will create `Users` you will need to provide `username`.
2. Create new layer, let say `UsersDto` which looks like this:

```
class UsersDto {
    var username: String
}
```

Which requires implementing some mapping between dto layer and entity. However, you'll need to handle nullable `username`, you can do it will forcing in the mapper `!!` (but only once) or

```
dto.username = entity.username ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Broken user, username is null!")
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to modify how you define your `Users` class:

```
@Entity
class Users(val username: String)
```

Comment: @Entity requires a no-arg constructor and to have that in kotlin you have to give it a default value beforehand or make it nullable